# Font-face embed (on website using CMS Made Simple) disappearing randomly on IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, embed, font-face, cmsmadesimple

I made a website with custom fonts embedded on the website using font-face. The font embed works fine across all major browsers on Windows, including IE7. However in IE6 the embedded fonts tend to disappear from time to time.

**This only occurs on the website after I have implemented on CMS Made Simple however (and then it only occurs on IE6 during navigation between pages).**

Template: http://www.vdpwebsites.com.au/tony/2011/bindara/index.html
(pages available: home, about us, stallions)

CMSMS: http://203.98.84.170/~bindara/

I think it might be a loading problem or something. On my template when I navigate/go between pages I can see the font first appearing in arial, before being replaced by the embedded font.

when you first go to the website on CMSMS the embedded font shows, but when you switch pages it gets stuck on arial. The only way to get it to show the embedded font again is to reload the page (ctrl F5) or clear the cache. Refresh doesn't do anything but replace the embedded font with arial if it was showing.

I'm running windows 7, and the IE6 is running off a Virtual PC. I'm not sure if the same would occur for someone who were using IE6 on their actual machine. Can anyone test this for me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the site on a remote IE6 machine.  I did not ever see the embedded font fail to load.  Though I did see Arial at first, after a few seconds the embedded font loaded.

Comment: Hi Katie, thanks for checking it for me. I tested mine on the Windows XP mode available in Windows 7 Professional and it seems there that on some occasions the font embedded just fails to load totally. Though this could just be related to my computer. I think I'll let this one slide. Thanks again!